# jqGrid: How to load all data when select all checkbox is activated?

Tags: jqgrid

I've got big jqGrids with ~1000-2000 rows, but only 100 are loaded by default.
I have multiselect set to true and use virtual scroll and when the select all checkbox is clicked only those rows which are already loaded get selected.

I told my users that as a workaround, they need to scroll down until all rows are loaded.
That works but is not very user friendly.

I would like a way to load the complete grid when "select all" is clicked.
There is an event called "onSelectAll" which I could use but I don't know how to load all data which is not yet loaded and select all rows again when the data finished loading.

Does anyone know a simple solution to this issue?

Comment: No :-( I increased the number of rows loaded to the total number of rows as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you add to your grid the option `loadonce: true`, jqGrid will ask for all data to the server.
I think that this way, all rows would be loaded at once.